# spotfire 4 columns expand

Tags: settings, spotfire

I am creating a pivot table that has 4 different categories. When I add the 4th category, the "column names" on the y-axis collapses and just says "4 columns". I would like this to continue to display the column names. Is there a way to do this so that my category names don't collapse after the 4th is entered? Below is a screenshot of what I am referring to:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZVv.jpg)

Comment: Is the area wide enough to show all of the text?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I enlarged the area of the graph (there used to be another graph next to it that crowded it, but I removed that). I played around with Spotfire a bit and it seems like 4 is the magic number. If there's enough room, it will display all 3 categories, but as soon as you go to 4 categories it will collapse everything.

Comment: Then I highly doubt there is anything you can do. That is just built in UI functionality. You could either use the developer tools to see the HTML/JS behind the scenes that is doing this and try to override it, or build your own chart with JS... but that all feels like overkill.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that was the case, there wasn't a setting that jumped out to me. Thanks!